# How to render data from javascript to html?

Tags: javascript, html, rendering

I am trying to create a forum website. I have created a `data1.js` file like so:

```
var threads = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "Thread 1",
        author: "Alice",
        date: Date.now(),
        content: "Thread content",
        comments: [
            {
                author: "Bob",
                date: Date.now(),
                content: "Hello world!"
            },
            {
                author: "Delta",
                date: Date.now(),
                content: "Hello everyone!"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "Thread 2",
        author: "Ekko",
        date: Date.now(),
        content: "Thread content",
        comments: [
            {
                author: "Foxtrot",
                date: Date.now(),
                content: "Hello everybody!"
            },
            {
                author: "Foo",
                date: Date.now(),
                content: "Hello hello!"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

In my `index.html`-file, I rendered data by pasting in a template string for each row (thread), and then rendering the vaiables dynamically, like so:

```
<body>
    <div class="top-bar">
        <h1>
            My Forum
        </h1>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        <ol> </ol>
    </div>

    <script src="data1.js"></script>    <!--Load script-->
    <script>
        console.log(threads); 

        //Create html for a row in string format
        var container = document.querySelector('ol');
        for (let thread of threads) {
            var rowHTML = `
                <li class="row"> 
                    <a href="/thread.html?key=${thread.id}"> 
                        <h4 class="title"> ${thread.title}</h4>
                        <div class="title-bottom">
                            <p class ="title-ts">${new Date(thread.date).toLocaleString()}</p>
                            <p class="comment-count">${thread.comments.length} comments</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            `
            //Paste it into the container
            container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', rowHTML);
        }
    </script>
```

And that seemed to work when I ran the browser; It shows two threads with two comments each, like it is in the data-file.
[image]

When I right-click on the file and click "Open with Edge"->"Open Browser", VS Code opens a URL that looks like this:

```
file:///C:\Users\PATH\TO\FILE\VSCodeProjects\Website-1\index1.html
```

and when I click on a thread, I get taken to the URL i defined in `<a href="/thread1.html?key=${thread.id}">`: `file:///C:/thread1.html?key=1`, and the whole page is blank. If I try to modify the URL to something like this: `<a href="\Users\PATH\TO\FILE\VSCodeProjects\Website-1\index1.html?key=${thread.id}">`, I still get a blank page when clicking on a thread.

When I tried to render the same way in my `thread.html`-file like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="top-bar">
        <h1>
            My Forum
        </h1>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="header"></div>
    
        <textarea></textarea>
        <button>Add comment</button>
    
        <div class="comments"></div>
    </div>

    <script defer src="data1.js"></script>    <!--Load script-->
    <script>
        console.log(threads);
        //Slice if from url for thread id
        var id = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('key'); //window.location.search.slice(1);
        var thread = threads.find(t => t.id == id);

        //Create html for header in string format
        var header = document.querySelector('.header');
        var headerHTML = `
            <h4 class="title">${thread.title}</h4>
            <div class="title-bottom">
                <p class ="title-ts">${new Date(thread.date).toLocaleString()}</p>
                <p class="comment-count">${thread.comments.length} comments</p>
            </div>
        `
        header.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', headerHTML);

        //Create html for comments in string format
        var comments = document.querySelector('.comments');
        for (let comment of thread.comments) {
            var commentHTML = `
                <div class="comment">
                    <div class="top-comment">
                        <p class="user">${comment.author}</p>
                        <p class="comment-ts">${new Date(comment.date).toLocaleString()}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="comment-content">${comment.content}</div>
                </div>
            `
            comments.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', commentHTML);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

It is not rendering the comments from the .js-file. It only shows `<h1>My Forum</h1>`, the text-area, and the "Add comment" button. When it should in addition show the thread title and the 2 comments for the thread that I created in the js-file.

I did it exactly the same way in the two files, but I get different results, I have checked that there are no errors in indentation and no added or missing s's, and I have tried to make sure I am looping into the correct place in the threads. I have tried to look through similar questions on here but I cannot find out what's wrong. Am I missing something or am I doing something wrong? Please, all help is appreciated!

**EDIT**
Added screenshot of console
[image]

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: `window.location.search.slice(1)` returns something like `key=value` and not `value`. They is no id like `key=value` in your array. Should be `var id = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('key name here')`

Comment: By 'key name here' I assume you mean the key in the javascript file? I have stored a key as 'id', do you think that can cause trouble?

Comment: I mean key in url example: `https://example.com?test=1` `key` is `test`

Comment: When I open the html-files in VS Code, the urls are like `PATH\TO\FILE\index.html` instead of f.ex. `127.0.0.1:5000/index.html`. Could this be part of the problem?